# Confusion with ruby `Marshal` concept

Tags: ruby, marshalling

[Marshal#dump](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) says:

> Serializes obj and all descendant objects. If an IO is specified, the serialized data will be written to it, otherwise the data will be returned as a String. ***If limit is specified, the traversal of sub-objects will be limited to that depth***. If limit is negative, no checking of depth will be performed.

Now my questions are:

> - What is depth?
> - Can you give me an example against the bold line?
> - Why `marshal_dump` will take precedence over `_dump` if both are defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - What is depth?
> - Can you give me an example against the bold line?

When marshalling an object, it can have references to another object, which can refer to yet another object. The depth level of this: `[1, 2, {"12" => [:foo]}]` is 4:

- Level 1: `[1, 2, {"12" => [:foo]}]`
- Level 2: `1`, `2` and `{"12" => [:foo]}`
- Level 3: `"12"` and `[:foo]`
- Level 4: `:foo`

Thus you can limit how many levels Marshal#dump will recursively look for:

```
Marshal.dump([1, 2, {"12" => [:foo]}], 4)
=> "\x04\b[\bi\x06i\a{\x06I\"\a12\x06:\x06ET[\x06:\bfoo"

Marshal.dump([1, 2, {"12" => [:foo]}], 3)
ArgumentError: exceed depth limit
```

> - Why `marshal_dump` will take precedence over `_dump` if both are defined?

The reason is that you should never define they both in your class at the same time, only one of them. One of them must be checked first anyway. The checking is done on the function `wobject` from [`marshal.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/marshal.c#L595).

Comment: doc is saying - `If limit is specified, the traversal of sub-objects will be limited to that depth`. then why `3` is not allowed? as it says we can limit the sub-objects travaersal depth?

Comment: It will go as long as the limit allows. If it cannot produce a complete dump of your object it will fail as there's no way to return partial and valid dumps.

Comment: why `Marshal.dump([1, 2, {"12" => [:foo]}], 5)` allowed? my confusion with that bold line still not clear.

Comment: because marshaling that array did not exceed 5 levels of depths, it's only 4, so the depth-barrier you gave was not violated. `Marshal.dump([1, 2, {"12" => [:foo]}], 1000)` it would still work, but `Marshal.dump([1, 2, {"12" => [:foo]}], 3)` and you have too little depth

Answer (score 1):

Concerning depth

Given:

```
h={'one'=>{'two'=>{'three'=>0}}}; p Marshal.dump(h,3)
```

Will issue:

```
ArgumentError: exceed depth limit
```

Meaning the marshal had to go beyond the given depth limit to marshal the object (3 hashes + the 'key-value' level of the last hash)

Whereas:

```
h={'one'=>{'two'=>{'three'=>0}}}; p Marshal.dump(h,4)
```

will work:

```
"\x04\b{\x06I\"\bone\x06:\x06ET{\x06I\"\btwo\x06;\x00T{\x06I\"\nthree\x06;\x00Ti\x00"
```

Comment: not getting the difference between two Hash. It seems both are equal. where they differs?

Comment: dang. sorry, forgot to change the level in the Marshal.dump call. the arrays are both the same

Comment: In essence you tell the marshaler: "If you can't marshal the object I give you within x levels, raise an error"
So as it can fully marshal the object with 4 levels of depth the depth-validation passed, so you get the marshaled object back

Comment: Looking at object here is `h` - how to determine the `depth`?

Comment: I guess it would make sense to assume it's 3 levels with 3 object-depths, but it seems its + 1? not sure why tho. maybe someone with more indepth knowledge can help you out

Comment: @Sascha: The example you gave has four depth levels: Hash/Hash/Hash/Fixnum. Marshal is probably running recursive code, and counting how many times it needs to process child objects, adding one to a depth counter each time it needs to. Not sure if there's a Ruby method to check an object's depth in general?